# Magento links missing index.php and are showing 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, database, 404, core-config-data

i'm having some problems with my website. when i try to access a different page like a product page, i get a 404 error, but when i add index.php in the link it works. i've tried to update the database table core_config_data for the web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url so that they include the index.php but then for some reason my theme isn't applied and the whole layout of the website is messed up as no styling is applied. Is there anyway i could include the index.php so that it is included in all url links as without it my pages show 404 errors.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: In admin panel goto system->configuration->left side(general)->web-> Use Web Server Rewrites-> set no

Comment: i don't have that option

Comment: which version you are using

Comment: i am using magento 1.9

Comment: it's ok glad to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In admin panel goto

```
system->configuration->left side(general)->web-> Use Web Server Rewrites-> set No
```